# How to expose biztalk orchestration as a web service

Tags: web-services, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have a hypothetical request to pull in 3 data fields into an orchestration but only via a web service.

how can I do this with biztalk?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

As @Tim has mentioned, the WCF Publishing Wizard is a good starting point.

*Overview:*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226350

More here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226564.aspx

*A couple of notes:*

You'll need to build and deploy your BTS project to a dev environment before you publish.
Make sure that when you publish you deploy to an app pool with the same user as the BizTalk Isolated host.

You don't actually need IIS / WAS to host the service - Biztalk can [self host](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/11/14/biztalk-in-process-hosting-of-wcf-http-services/) with e.g. WCF-Custom. So you can avoid the Isolated host in your production environment and turn off IIS entirely. This has performance and resource benefits. 
Note that you may need to open up permissions for BizTalk to listen see [here](http://henwor.wordpress.com/?s=netsh) or [here](http://dipeshavlani.net/2009/11/)

Publishing and 'refreshing' the WSDL in a dev environment so that peer systems can create proxies etc can be a pain. After using the publishing wizard, you can use this tool to refresh your WSDL publication without having to redo the wizard.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21973

Answer (score 1):

Use the "BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard". It will walk you through all the steps you need.